# Difference between captured TLS handshakes

Tags: ssl, handshake

I am trying to understand TLS. I captured communication from browser to various sites. I tried to google but could not find anything that clarifies why in some of the captures I have 'Certificate Status' except of 'Certificate' in a reply from the server.
Please have a look at the screenshot to get a better understanding to what I exactly refer to.

In short my question is - why sometimes some servers reply not only with a certificate but also certificate status and the others only with a certificate?

[on the screenshot are communications with 3 different sites. 2 of them with certificate status, 1 without certificate status - Please focus on marked with the red color parts of communication]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ezpw.png

[I find status_request extension in all communications, but not everywhere it is answered with Certificate status:]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxp4b.png

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check the client's TLS extensions to see if the client requested OCSP status from the server. You'd find more details on the extension in this RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066

Comment: And v2 in rfc6961. Note TLS1.3 changes this: OCSP although still optional is now included as an extension in the Certificate message and not a separate message.

Comment: Hello user3224083, thank you for the answer. I read about the status_request extension, but that is in both communications. In both 'Client Hello' I find extension named 'status_request' with the certificate status type: OCSP(1). In spite of that 1 server replies with Certifcate and Certificate Status, while the other replies with Certificate only. I edited and attached the second screenshot so you can see the extension.

Comment: @xyz I think that may have to do with the verbiage in the RFC (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6066#section-8):

Essentially, the server is NOT REQUIRED to comply with the `status_request`. Notice the usage of the word MAY in the RFC to describe what is required of the server upon receiving the `status_request`.

Comment: @xyz Did the reference from section 8 of the RFC help you understand the difference in the servers' behavior? Also, if the answer gives an adequate explanation to your question, would you be so kind as to accept the answer? Here's a general guide for dealing with answers/comments on your post. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers